# Passing Values from One Form to another redirected Form in PHP

Tags: php, forms, redirect, action

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="store.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">REGISTRATION DATE</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="date" class="form-control1" name="reg_date" id="focusedinput" placeholder="Default Input">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <p class="help-block">text!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">REGISTRATION No.</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="reg_no" id="focusedinput" placeholder="Default Input">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <p class="help-block">text!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
            <input type="SUBMIT" value="Next" class="form-control1">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here, in this code there are more input types, I just skipped those. When I will press submit button this will take me to 'store.php' file where informations will be stored in database. And redirect me to another form and there are also some input type but I need a information like "reg_no" from the previous form in the current form. How can I get this?

**NOTE :** I am storing the inputs of first form in a database table. Then redirected to other form and the action of this form is another PHP file like 'store2.php' and it is also using to store informations to other table of database.

Comment: Why don't you simply capture $_POST['reg_no'] from first form in store.php and have an input element with reg_no in the next form ?!

Comment: Ok..if you are redirecting to another ...page, then pass the variable as SESSION variable...and capture it in the next form

Comment: Thanks @user3526204 , I tried it before using $_SESSION but didn't work. Now it is working nice. May be i was wrong in some point but thank you to remind me to think again about $_SESSION ...

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Want to consider this as an answer ? I will put it in the answer area :)

Comment: Yes you may put it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the value of reg_no as a

> $_SESSION Variable

to the second form and get it there

Comment: @rokiDGupta Wondering why this was chosen as the answer first and changed to the current one later....that also says the same thing eitherways..! :)

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are already passing the information from your current form into a database. When rendering your second form, you could grab whatever value you need from your database, and then add a `value` attribute to your input.

So for example if you have a form that looks like this in your second form:

`<input type="text" class="form-control1" name="reg_no" id="focusedinput" placeholder="Default Input">`

You can add that class to Pre-Fill the form when the page loads. Lets say you want it to show "12345":

`<input type="text" class="form-control1" name="reg_no" id="focusedinput" placeholder="Default Input" value="12345">`

I don't know the details of exactly how you are serving your site through PHP, but you could use some kind of string placeholder, or templating engine to put in this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you :

this called **form.php** :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="form_p.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">REGISTRATION DATE</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="date" class="form-control1" name="reg_date" id="focusedinput" placeholder="Default Input">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <p class="help-block">text!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">REGISTRATION No.</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="reg_no" id="focusedinput" placeholder="Default Input">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <p class="help-block">text!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
      <input name="submit" type="SUBMIT" value="Next" class="form-control1">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

this process of form.php, called **form_p.php** :

```
<?php
$reg_date = $_POST['reg_date'];
$reg_no = $_POST['reg_no'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if (isset($submit)) {
    $url = 'form_next.php?reg_date=' . $reg_date . '&reg_no=' . $reg_no;
    header('Location:' . $url);
}
```

this next form, **called form_next.php** :

```
<?php
$reg_date = $_GET['reg_date'];
$reg_no = $_GET['reg_no'];
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="form_p_next.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">REGISTRATION DATE AGAIN</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="date" class="form-control1" name="reg_date" id="focusedinput" placeholder="Default Input" value="<?php echo $reg_date; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <p class="help-block">text!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">REGISTRATION No. AGAIN</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="reg_no" id="focusedinput" placeholder="Default Input" value="<?php echo $reg_no; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <p class="help-block">text!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
      <input name="submit" type="SUBMIT" value="Next" class="form-control1">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and this is process of form_next.php, called **form_next_p.php**

```
<?php
//define your code
```

The code work because I passing reg_date and reg_no from form_p.php to form_next.php and I use $_GET to get reg_date and reg_no and print it in input value.
This is help you?